# How can I stop Visual Studio from prompting "IntelliCode multiline suggestion"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Sometimes when I create an autoproperty (e.g. `public NewsItemFilters { get; set; }`), the "IntelliCode multiline suggestion" option appears and, the moment I hit the `;`, it automatically fills in some code like this:

```cs
public NewsItemFilters Filters {
    get;
}; }
```

I know I can just pause after typing the member name, and then hit tab when prompted for `{ get; set; }`, but I do like just typing it myself as that's what my muscle memory is.

[image]

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: I wonder if this is apart of Intellicode.  I have Intellicode "show whole line completions" turned off - maybe that helps? Can also try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/intellicode-suggestions?view=vs-2022#disable-intellicode-suggestions but you probably will lose more that just this functionality